# Solution of fractional laplancian when $s\rightarrow 1^{-}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $(-\Delta)^{s}$ the fractional laplacian operator. Suppose that the problem
$$ (-\Delta)^{s}u_{s}(x)= f(u_{s}(x)), x \in \Omega$$
$$ u_{s} = 0 \textrm{ in } \mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\Omega $$

has a regular solution (i.e Hölder continuous) for each $s \in (0,1)$. What happens to this solution when we take $s \rightarrow 1^{-}$ and when $s\rightarrow 0^{+}$? I mean, does exists a function $u$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}}u_{s} = u$ and $-\Delta u = f(u)$? If it is true, does $u$ preserve the qualitative properties of $u_{s}$?.

Here the fractional Lpalacian is defined in the P.V sense. The set $\Omega$ is open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{1}$ function.

Comment: Can you clean up the question a little? (1) For bounded domains, I recall that there are a number of non-equivalent definitions of $(-\Delta)^s$. So please include the definition you are using. (2) You write $u_s$ in the PDE but prescribe the values of $u$ and not $u_s$ outside $\Omega$? (3) What sort of qualitative properties are you hoping to preserve?

Comment: @BBVM: What do you understand by "regular solution"? What are the properties of $f$? Is $\Omega$ relatively compact?